# PHP Accessing Constants Dynamically from abstract class

Tags: php

I am stuck with a problem I thought was easily resolved, but at a loss. I have an abstract class which has several constants that define time increments which looks something like this.

```
abstract class DictionaryKeepAliveIncrements{

    CONST second        = 1;
    CONST quarterminute = 15;
    CONST halfminute    = 30;
    CONST minute        = 60;
```

I am trying to access them dynamically from another class like so

```
public function getKeepAliveByUnit($timeUnit){
    return constant('DictionaryKeepAliveIncrements::'.$timeUnit);
}
```

This is resulting in the error

> **Warning**:  constant(): Couldn't find constant
>   DictionaryKeepAliveIncrements::minute in

The *DictionaryKeepAliveIncrements* is in the same namespace as the method *getKeepAliveByUnit* so should see it. I've also tried adding the full namespace but get the same result.

What am I missing?

Comment: Are you calling `$thing->getKeepAliveByUnit('second');` instead of just accessing `DictionaryKeepAliveIncrements::second`? You seem to be massively overcomplicating things here...

Comment: Yes, I am calling `$instance->getKeepAliveByUnit('week')` I am having to deal with some legacy code where configuration options are dynamically set in other parts of the code and then passed through. Otherwise I would hardcode it it in place using `DictionaryKeepAliveIncrements::minute` where it is needed.

Comment: Is there a derived class from this abstract class that has been instantiated at all?  I am wondering if as it is part of an abstract perhaps the constants haven't been defined if there is nothing using the abstract.  If you remove the `abstract` keyword does it work?

Comment: It may be safer to use `switch`, check for each valid input and return the corresponding constant.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to include namespace in the `constant()` call - see [code @ 3v4l.org](https://3v4l.org/6WYgY)

**EDIT**
To correct the problem adding namespace was the solution. The following solved the problem.

To better explain this solution here is what was needed.

```
public function getKeepAliveByUnit($timeUnit){
    return constant('root\namespace\DictionaryKeepAliveIncrements::'.$timeUnit);
}
```